# Using perl to replace accented word with no accent and associated number

Tags: regex, perl, replace

Any accented word needs the accent to be removed and then a corresponding number should be added at the end of the word.

**Example:*

```
gàr must appear as gar3
```

▶ Words will only show acute accent and grave accent which should translate respectively as 2 and 3 added at the end of the word.

▶ Words might be concomitant with spaces, tabs, return, hyphen ( long or short ), parenthesis, question marks, etc.

▶ Words will include non ASCII chars like shin ( s with a funny upside down hat on it )

Can anyone suggest the right structure, regex and replacement pattern?

Thanks !

Here is a sample for testing :

```
14 IGI <DIŠ>⌈x⌉-èr-ra 
15 IGI <DIŠ>bu-ṣí-ia 
16 IGI <DIŠ>su-ka-lum
17 IGI <DIŠ>ì-lí-tu-[...x-...x] 
18 ⌈MU⌉<ON:>KI.BAL.BAR.RÚ:KI
```

It should result in :

```
14 IGI <DIŠ>⌈x⌉-er3-ra
15 IGI <DIŠ>bu-ṣi2-ia
16 IGI <DIŠ>su-ka-lum
17 IGI <DIŠ>i3-li2-tu-[...x-...x]
18 ⌈MU⌉<ON:>KI.BAL.BAR.RU2:KI
```

Comment: I don't know *how* you could do this, but Unicode can be normalized, so that diacritical marks and the main character are seperated into two or more code points, although they still make up one *grapheme*. Once that is done, stripping them it out is easy. I.e. `ê` really is "`^e`" etc. [Unicode::Normalize](http://search.cpan.org/~sadahiro/Unicode-Normalize-1.14/Normalize.pm) could help, never seen it before.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) has further information on normalization. And `ê` actually is more like `e^`

Comment: Can't seem to edit the comments -- so here is a permalink to [`Unicode::Normalize`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Unicode-Normalize/Normalize.pm); the other link is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an inactive question, but since it might be useful for people searching similar problems, here's the code that does exactly what you asked for:

```
use utf8;
use Unicode::Normalize;

my $text='IGI <DIŠ>bu-ṣí-ia'; #your input data

my $x=NFD($text); #Normalization Form D (1)
$x=~s/\x{300}/3/g; #substitute grave accents with number 3 (2)
$x=~s/\x{301}/2/g; #substitute acute accents with number 2 (2)
$x=NFC($x); #Normalization Form C (1)
print $x; #prints "IGI <DIŠ>bu-ṣi2-ia"
```

<sup>1</sup> I'm not a Unicode expert so I'm inadequate to explain clearly & properly what those functions do exactly. [These](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) [articles](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms) or [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=unicode+normalization+forms) might give you a better idea.

<sup>2</sup> Check the [Unicode table](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html) for values 300 & 301.

Comment: Hey psxls, it works with that line but with the first line èr becomes e3r instead of er3

Comment: Hi Sohnyrin. I would suggest to post-process the output. For example before printing `$x` you could run a substitution `$x=~s/\b([a-z]{1,2})(\d)([a-z]{1,2})\b/$1$3$2/gi;`. This is a dirty solution but I don't fully understand what your data is all about to give you clean solution. Try the above and experiment, I think you will find a way.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I do not need it to be pretty and the processing can be done in many steps it does not matter. It works. Thanks a bunch ! :-)